# Ruby on Rails: + AJAX: How do I set the value of a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

there is

```
page.replace_html "id", thing to replace it with
```

but is there something where I can just insert a value into a text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found was to do this:

```
page[:object_column_name].value = whatever
```

its just the id of the field

Comment: OK, that seems like the simplest way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to drop out of **RJS** and into *Prototype* for this one. For example, if your `textfield` id has a value "foo" then something like this might work:

```
page << %{
  var input = $('foo');

  input.writeAttribute('value', 'thing to replace it with');
}
```

updates the `value` attribute of the `input` element.